# Make a condition from array

Tags: vue.js, twig

I need your help, i tried many attempts without success, from my php controller i have following array :

```
$products = array(
    'name' => 'shirt'
    array(
        'attribues' => array(
            array("code" => "1", "label"=>"xs"),
            array("code" => "2-", "label"=>"small"),
            ...
        )
    )
    ....
);
```

In product categories page, where i list all products i have following twig for an product item :

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here the aim it to able to filter by products attributes keys so i think something like this, the "product_tab" is a value from a tab where i click  :

```
{% for product in products %}
     <div v-if="[{{product.attributes|keys|join(',')}}].includes(selected_code)">{{ product.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The tab list :

```
<div data-tab="1" :click="show_products">xs</div>
<div data-tab="2-" :click="show_products">small</div>

// the vuejs part
const app = {
    data() {
        selected_code:"1"
    },
    methods:{
        show_products:function(e){
            this.selected_code = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-tab")
        }
    }
}
```

But i get error in console, vuejs as **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','** and it brokes the page rendering. I know that the error is because of this line :

```
v-if="[{{product.attributes|keys|join('"','"')}}].includes(selected_code)"
```

But i don't know how to make this working, when i dump products.attributes|keys|join like below :

```
dump(product.attributes|keys|join('"','"'));
```

it outputs :

```
"["1-","18-total=0.5","81-"]"
```

You notice the double quotes around, I'm stumped and I can't find what to do to make this page work.

Comment: If you want twig data in javascript you're better of with `json_encode: v-if='{{ attributes|keys|json_encode|raw }}'`

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems working, i will test with another datas